# No SharePoint Jobs in the portal

Tags: discussion

I was just going through the Job page of StackExchange and could find jobs for almost ll technology but not SharePoint. Am I looking at the right place or there is no more SharePoint need in the world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many SharePoint opportunities out there, but the only place where you'll find announcements for a job is on StackOverflow, which is going to be mainly for programming languages related things, you won't find as many SharePoint results as when you search for JavaScript or Front-end developer opportunities for example.

To find posts related to SharePoint I would suggest looking at sites like Monster, Indeed, or even LinkedIn.

Comment: Dice.com is honestly going to be your best bet. They only post technology jobs.